# File format validation django admin

Tags: django, import, admin, django-import-export

I am using django import/export in my project.In my admin model i have two fields "choose file" for choosing files and "select format" for selecting formats csv, xls and json. how can i do java-script validation to make sure that user chooses only one of the 3 file types? how to validate the chosen file extension and selected format are same?

Comment: @RajaSimon where should i write that java-script? and how can i make the inbuilt import/export template use that java-script ?

Answer (score 1):

It's does not need javascript to do. Just use formats `attributes` from `ImportMixin`.

```
class BookResource(resources.ModelResource):
    formats = (<class 'import_export.formats.base_formats.CSV'>, 
               <class 'import_export.formats.base_formats.XLS'>, 
               <class 'import_export.formats.base_formats.JSON'>)
    class Meta:
        model = Boo
```

Links: `formats`